# Remove duplicate rows using Qualify in Teradata

Tags: duplicates, teradata, partition, row-number, teradata-sql-assistant

I have the following data in one of my Teradata tables and I would like to delete duplicate rows based on three different variables

```
 Have

 ID    CDate        DDate         Seq
 101   4/25/2020    5/24/2020     1201
 101   4/25/2020    5/26/2020     1201
 101   4/26/2020    5/24/2020     1202
 101   4/26/2020    5/26/2020     1202

Want

 ID    CDate        DDate         Seq
 101   4/25/2020    5/24/2020     1201
 101   4/26/2020    5/26/2020     1202
```

Using the following query

```
Qualify row_number() Over (Partition By ID, CDate, DDate ORDER BY Seq)=1
```

I still get the same 4 rows as `output`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you add more details, why do want those two rows?

Comment: That gives me distinct CDate, DDate for Seq

Comment: But why rows 1 & 4 and not 2 & 3 or 2 & 4?

Comment: 2 & 3 will have the DDate in descending order and 2 & 4 will leave the same DDate which I don't want